# $A.getCallback() [Action failed: c:COMP_PsFlow$controller$doInit [Cannot read property '1' of null]] Failing descriptor:

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

I'm getting the below error when I'm trying to run the flow. Could someone please help me?

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.

> Error in $A.getCallback() [Action failed: c:BELL_COMP_CarePassFlow$controller$doInit [Cannot read property '1' of null]] Failing descriptor: {markup://flowruntime:flowRuntimeV2}

Below is my controller.js

```
({
    handleGoBack : function(component){
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
            var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
            workspaceAPI.closeTab({tabId: focusedTabId});
        })
    },
    /*onTabClosed : function(component, event, helper) {
        var tabId = event.getParam('tabId');
        console.log("Tab closed: " +tabId);
    },*/
    
    closeFocusedTab : function(component, event, helper) {
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
            var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
            console.log("Tab Focused: " +focusedTabId);
            //workspaceAPI.closeTab({tabId: focusedTabId});
       })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        
        //Get Extra Care Card Number and Pass to Continuation, then Launch Flow
        console.log('hey1:::');
        console.log('component.get("v.recordId")::'+component.get("v.recordId"));
        // console.log(component.get("v.pageReference").state.testAttribute);
        // component.find("articleURL").set("v.value", window.location.pathname);
        console.log('window.location.pathname::'+window.location.pathname);
        console.log('window.location.href::'+window.location.href);
        var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
        var url, captured, result;
        if(recId == undefined || recId == null){
            url = window.location.href; // or window.location.href for current url
            captured = url ? /CaseRecordId=([^&]+)/.exec(url)[1] : ''; // Value is in [1] ('384' in our case)
            result = captured ? captured : 'myDefaultValue';
            component.set("v.recordId", result);
            /*component.set("v.recordId", "5004C000006DU5FQAW");*/
        }
        
        
        console.log('url:::'+url);
        console.log('result:::'+result);
        
        console.log('component.get("v.recordId")::'+component.get("v.recordId"));
        
        //helper.myTestFunction2();
        helper.getExtraCareCardNum(component);
        console.log('hey2:::');
        let inputParam = {caseId: component.get("v.recordId")};
    },
    // onPageReferenceChange: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    //     var myPageRef = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
    //     var recordId = myPageRef.state.c__CaseId;
    //     console.log('c__NewChild: '+id);
    //     cmp.set("v.recordId", recordId);
    // },
    // refreshIt: function(component, event, helper){
    //     component.find('accForm').submit();
    //     var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
    //      var navService = component.find("navigationService");
    //     var pageReference = {
    
    //         "type": "standard__component",
    //         "attributes": {
    //             "componentName": "c__acapChecklist"    
    //         },    
    //         "state": {
    //              recordId: recordId
    //         }
    //     };
    //     navService.navigate(pageReference);    
    // }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript `RegExp.exec()` method [returns `null` if it does not match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

> The `exec()` method executes a search for a match in a specified string. Returns a result array, or null.

It appears that your regex is not matching the current URL when you load this component in your Flow.